# Ruby on Rails - access user defined lib functions in /lib/login_system.rb from app/views/layouts/_menu.rhtml

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, ruby-on-rails

I have defined a function called `is_logged_in?` in a user defined library stored in the /lib directory, however when I try to use it in one of my views (in this case a _menu.html.erb view) I get a "undefined method `is_logged_in?' for #" error. I had assumed that if the method was available within the /lib directory then it would be accessible through the application?

my login_system.rb file is as follows:

```
module LoginSystem
  protected

  def is_logged_in?
    @logged_in_user = User.find(session[:user]) if session[:user]
  end

  def logged_in_user
    return @logged_in_user if is_logged_in?
  end

  def logged_in_user=(user)
    if !user.nil?
      session[:user] = user.id
      @logged_in_user = user
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :is_logged_in, :logged_in_user
  end
end
```

and my _menu.html.erb file is as follows:

```
<ul>
 <li><%= link_to 'Home', '/' %></li>
 <li><%= link_to 'Edit Page', pages_path %></li>

 <li><hr size = "1" width = "90%" aligh = "left" /></li>

 <% if is_logged_in? %>
  <li> Logged in as: <i><%= logged_in_user.username%> </i></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Logout',{:controller => 'account', :action => 'logout'}, :method => :post%> </li>
 <% else %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new' %> </li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Login', :controller => 'account', :action => 'login' %></li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Can anyone point where I've gone wrong?

Bernard

Comment: Woops, the _menu file is actually a _menu.rhtml - NOT _menu.html.erb as specified above. Not sure if this makes a difference?

Comment: Just figured it out... it was a STUPID syntax error in my login_system.rb file that caused it to fail. I forgot the ? in the following statement...

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :is_logged_in, :logged_in_user
  end

Needed to change to 
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :is_logged_in?, :logged_in_user
  end

Gggrrr....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include 'login_system'
end
```

Comment: My Application Controller has that already. 

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include LoginSystem
end

Any other suggestion?

Ps. I tried changing the syntax to the one you showed above and I got an error "wrong argument type String (expected Module)"

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try [devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).
If you don't have some seriously different needs for login/logout accounts then it is great!